# gzsdf: command not found with Gazebo 4.0.2 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

I'm running Gazebo 4.0.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.
I installed Gazebo with the one-line command given [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install&cat=get_started).

I have a URDF file that I want to load in Gazebo. This file is given to me by somebody else and I don't have ROS installed. Following [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_urdf&cat=connect_ros#VerifyingtheGazeboModelWorks), I want to use `gzsdf` to convert the URDF file to SDF.

However, when I try to run `gzsdf`, the command is not found. I also can't find the binary in my file system.
Where should it be located? What do I need to do to get it?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7149/gzsdf:-command-not-found-with-gazebo-4.0.2-on-ubuntu-14.04/) by [NickDP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/964/nickdp/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 186 on 2014-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found that the binary gz has a command sdf, which does what gzsdf is described to do.
So the command

```
gzsdf print MODEL.urdf
```

as given in the tutorial is now

```
gz sdf -p MODEL.urdf
```

Is this a recent change? This should probably be changed in the tutorial then?

---

Originally posted by [NickDP](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/964/nickdp/) with karma: 186 on 2014-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose Luis Rivero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/152/jose-luis-rivero/) on 2014-10-03**:
Since gazebo-3.0, http://gazebosim.org/blog/gazebo3. https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo_tutorials/pull-request/96/include-fix-for-gzsdf-on-gaebo3-and-above